# Stemming: remove/change URL with regex module in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, stemming

Hello I'm trying to do Stemming in Python, and I want to remove or change URL (https/http) with Regex module. I already write some lines of code but it seems only work for punctuation not for emoticon and URL, anyone please help me? here's my code

```
 def tokenWordbase(verse):
    return verse.split(' ')

#URLs
def url(link):
    link = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', link, flags=re.MULTILINE)

#punctuation
def punctuation(tokens):
    tokens = re.sub(r'[>)}:{",?+ !.(<;1234567890]','',str(tokens))
    tokens = re.sub('\n','',str(tokens))
    return tokens

#emot
def emoticons(emot):
    emot = re.sub( ':-)', ':)', '(:', '(-:', ':-D', ':D', 'X-D', 'XD', 'xD', ';-)', ';)', ';-D', ';D', '(;', '(-;', ':-(', ':(', '(:', '(-:', ':,(', ':\'(', ':"(', ':((', str(tokens))
    return emot

def main():
    currentString = []
    panjangTang = []
    with open('Book2.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == '' or row[0] == '-':
                continue
            else:
                tokennya = tokenWordbase(row[0])
                panjangTangSementara = []
                for j in range(len(tokennya)):
                    # print(childToken)
                    puntu = punctuation(tokennya[j])
                    stopnya = stopword.remove(puntu)
                    if stopnya == '':
                        continue
                    else:
                        stemmnya = stemmer.stem(stopnya)
                        currentString.append(stemmnya)
                        panjangTangSementara.append(stemmnya)
                panjangTang.append(panjangTangSementara)
    daftarDokumen = Counter(currentString)
    daftarString = []
```

Answer (score 0):

domain_registers = [".com",".net",".info",".biz","mobi",".xxx",".asia",".eu",".name",".us",".co",".org",".me",".mx",".in",".ac",".asp",".php",".html"]

def url(link):
    if ('.' in link and '/' in link) or 'www.' in link or 'http' in link or any([word in link for word in domain_registers]):
        return ""

Answer (score 0):

The `url` function is not returning the modified string, try adding `return link` to the end of it.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a more minimal example to pinpoint the error, like only the url function with a fixed string as input and printing the output.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)